# how to pause a jquery timer when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do i stop the timer when it goes hidden it just keeps running but it is supposed to start running again when it gets displayed again.

when it is displayed at first it start correctly but than it keeps running while t is hidden but is supposed to start running when it is displayed again.

it is supposed for tablets so i recommend running it while inspecting elements in a smaller screen.

```js
// document.addEventListener('touchstart', this.touchstart);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', this.touchmove);

// function touchstart(e) {
//     e.preventDefault()
// }

function touchmove(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
}

var aNote = document.getElementById('aAudio')
$('#ring-animatie').mouseover(function(){
 aNote.currentTime = 0;
 aNote.play();
});

 $('.activate-date').click(function() {
        
        if ($('#gaop').hasClass('active')) {
           
            $('#gaop').removeClass('active').addClass('hidden');

            $('#beeindig').removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');

             $('#timer').removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');

            $('#knop').addClass('begin-date').addClass('shake');

            $('#knop-deel2').addClass('begin-date').addClass('shake');



        } else {
            
            $('#gaop').removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');
            $('#beeindig').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
            $('#timer').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
            $('#knop').removeClass('begin-date').removeClass('shake');
            $('#knop-deel2').removeClass('begin-date').removeClass('shake');

        }
            
            $.ajax({ url: 'https://18003.hosts.ma-cloud.nl/light/script.php',
        data: {
            'hoi': 'hoi'
        },
        type: 'post',
        success: function(output) {
  console.log(output);
            //if(checkCount == counter){ location.reload(); }
        }
    });
        
    }); 



function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {

            $('#gaop').removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');
            $('#beeindig').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
            $('#timer').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
            $('#knop').removeClass('begin-date').removeClass('shake');
            $('#knop-deel2').removeClass('begin-date').removeClass('shake');
            timer = duration;

            
        }


    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) {
    var twoMinutes = 60 * 2,
        display = $('#time');
    startTimer(twoMinutes, display);
});
```

```css
/* CSS Document */

@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bree+Serif);

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Opensans-regular';
    src: url(../fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}



body {
     background: url(../img/mockup_bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
     -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    background-color: black;
    font-size:22px;
    line-height: 32px;
    color: #ffffff;
    word-wrap:break-word !important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    }


h1 {
    font-size: 60px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}   

h3 {
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}

h3 a {
    color: #FFF;
}

a {
    color: #FFF;
}
h1 {margin-top: 100px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:60px;
    font-family: 'Bree Serif', 'serif';
    }

p {
    text-align: center;
}


div.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    
}

div.center{

position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;

}

.activate-date {
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    top: 35%;
    z-index: 3;
}
p.text-hint{
    font-family: 'Opensans-regular';
    color: white;
    font-weight: 120%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

div.center div.text-timer{
    font-family: 'Opensans-regular';
    color: white;
    font-weight: 120%;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 42%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

}


.active{
    display: block;
}

.hidden{

    display: none;
}


#knop {

 margin: 0px auto;
    height: 400px;
 width: 400px;
    border: 10px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 60px white,
             inset 0 0 60px white;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 60px white,
            inset 0 0 60px white;
            box-shadow: 0 0px 60px white,
            inset 0 0 60px white;
            text-align: center;
    margin-top: 35%;
 }

#knop-deel2{
    margin: 0px auto;
    height: 400px;
    width: 400px;
    border: 10px solid white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 60px white,
             inset 0 0 60px white;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 60px white,
            inset 0 0 60px white;
            box-shadow: 0 0px 60px white,
            inset 0 0 60px white;
            text-align: center;
    margin-top: 35%;

    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: fixed;

}


div#knop.begin-date,
div#knop-deel2.begin-date{
    border: 12px solid #c91c71;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 60px #c91c71,
             inset 0 0 60px red;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 60px #c91c71,
            inset 0 0 60px #c91c71;
            box-shadow: 0 0px 60px #c91c71,
            inset 0 0 60px #c91c71;
}

.animated { 
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
 
  animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
} 

 
/*
 * Animation for webkit
*/
@-webkit-keyframes bounce { 
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);} 
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);} 
} 
  
@keyframes bounce { 
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {transform: translateY(-30px);} 
    60% {transform: translateY(-15px);} 
} 
  
/*
 * Adding the animation to our element
*/
.bounce { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce; 
    animation-name: bounce; 
}


/*
 ring-binnen
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes ring-binnen { 
     0% { transform: scale(1); } 
    25% { transform: scale(0.9);}
    48% { transform: scale(1.15);}
    50% { transform: scale(1.2); } 
    75% { transform: scale(1.05);}
    100% { transform: scale(1); } 
} 
@keyframes ring-binnen { 
    0% { transform: scale(1); } 
    25% { transform: scale(0.9);}
    48% { transform: scale(1.15);}
    50% { transform: scale(1.2); } 
    75% { transform: scale(1.05);}

    100% { transform: scale(1); } 
} 
.ring-binnen { 
    -webkit-animation-name: ring-binnen; 
    animation-name: ring-binnen; 
}


/*
 ring-buiten
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes ring-buiten{ 
   0% { transform: scale(1); opacity: 0; } 
    25% { transform: scale(0.9);}
    48% { transform: scale(1.15);}
    50% { transform: scale(1.2); opacity: 1;} 
    75% { transform: scale(1.25);opacity: 1;}
    85% { transform: scale(1.4); opacity: 0.5;}
    100% { transform: scale(1.45); opacity: 0; } 
} 
@keyframes ring-buiten { 
    0% { transform: scale(1); opacity: 0; } 
    25% { transform: scale(0.9);}
    48% { transform: scale(1.15);}
    50% { transform: scale(1.2); opacity: 1;} 
    75% { transform: scale(1.25);opacity: 1;}
    85% { transform: scale(1.4); opacity: 0.5;}
    100% { transform: scale(1.45); opacity: 0; } 
} 
.ring-buiten { 
    -webkit-animation-name: ring-buiten; 
    animation-name: ring-buiten; 
}


/*
 * Flash animation
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes flash { 
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;} 
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0;} 
} 
@keyframes flash { 
    0%, 50%, 100% {opacity: 1;} 
    25%, 75% {opacity: 0;} 
} 
.flash { 
    -webkit-animation-name: flash; 
    animation-name: flash; 
}


/*
 * Shake animation
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes shake { 
    0%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateX(0);} 
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {-webkit-transform: translateX(-10px);} 
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {-webkit-transform: translateX(10px);} 
} 
@keyframes shake { 
    0%, 100% {transform: translateX(0);} 
    10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {transform: translateX(-10px);} 
    20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {transform: translateX(10px);} 
} 
.shake { 
    -webkit-animation-name: shake; 
    animation-name: shake; 
}




/**************************************/
/***********background bellen**********/
/**************************************/

.bg-bel{
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    position: fixed;
    border: 4px solid #7ccced;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0px 6px white,
             inset 0 0 6px white;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0px 6px white,
            inset 0 0 6px white;
            box-shadow: 0 0px 6px white,
            inset 0 0 6px white;
            z-index: -20;
}



.animated-bg { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 30s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    
    animation-name: bounceIn;
    animation-duration: 30s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease-out;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
} 

/*
bg ring 1
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ring { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 76%; left: 40%; bottom: 20%; right: 60%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 110%; left: 30%; bottom: -10%; right: 70%;} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ring { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 76%; left: 40%; bottom: 20%; right: 60%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 102%; left: 30%; bottom: -10%; right: 70%;} 
} 
.bg-ring { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ring; 
    animation-name: bg-ring; 
}

/*
bg ring 2
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringtwee { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 20%; left: 60%; bottom: 76%; right: 40%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: -10%; left: 70%; bottom: 102%; right: 30%;} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringtwee { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 20%; left: 60%; bottom: 76%; right: 40%; opacity:*/ 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: -10%; left: 70%; bottom: 102%; right: 30%;} 
} 
.bg-ringtwee { 
    border: #7ccced;
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringtwee; 
    animation-name: bg-ringtwee; 
}

/*
bg ring 3
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringdrie { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 40%; left: 76%; bottom: 60%; right: 20%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 30%; left: 102%; bottom: 70%; right: -10%;} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringdrie { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 40%; left: 76%; bottom: 60%; right: 20%; opacity:*/ 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 30%; left: 102%; bottom: 70%; right: -10%;} 
} 
.bg-ringdrie { 
    border: #7ccced;
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringdrie; 
    animation-name: bg-ringdrie; 
}

/*
bg ring 4
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringvier{ 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 60%; left: 20%; bottom: 40%; right: 76%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 70%; left: -10%; bottom: 30%; right: 102%;} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringvier { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 60%; left: 20%; bottom: 20%; right: 76%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 70%; left: -10%; bottom: 30%; right: 102%;} 
} 
.bg-ringvier { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringvier; 
    animation-name: bg-ringvier; 
}

/*
bg ring 7
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringzeven{ 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 76%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 50%; left: -2%; bottom: 50%; right: 102%;} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringzeven { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 50%; left: 20%; bottom: 50%; right: 76%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 50%; left: -2%; bottom: 50%; right: 102%;} 
} 
.bg-ringzeven { 
    border: #7ccced;
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringzeven; 
    animation-name: bg-ringzeven; 
}

/*
bg ring 6
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringzes{ 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 50%; left: 76%; bottom: 50%; right: 20%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 50%; left: 102%; bottom: 50%; right: -10%;} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringzes { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);} 
    50% {/*top: 50%; left: 76%; bottom: 50%; right: 20%;*/ opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
  /*  25% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;} 
    75% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%;}*/
    100% { top: 50%; left: 122%; bottom: 50%; right: -20%;} 
} 
.bg-ringzes { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringzes; 
    animation-name: bg-ringzes; 
}

/*
bg ring 8
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringacht{ 
   0% { top: 50%; left: 76%; bottom: 50%; right: 100%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 

    48% {  opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    49% { top: 50%; left: 122%; bottom: 50%; right: -20%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    

    100% { top: 50%; left: 76%; bottom: 50%; right: 100%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringacht { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 76%; bottom: 50%; right: 10%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 

    48% {  opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    49% { top: 50%; left: 122%; bottom: 50%; right: -20%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    

    100% { top: 50%; left: 76%; bottom: 50%; right: 10%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
.bg-ringacht { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringacht; 
    animation-name: bg-ringacht; 
}

/*
bg ring 9
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringnegen{ 
   0% { top: 50%; left: 76%; bottom: 50%; right: 100%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 

    48% {  opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    49% { top: 50%; left: 122%; bottom: 50%; right: -20%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    

    100% { top: 50%; left: 76%; bottom: 50%; right: 100%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringnegen { 
    0% { top: 50%; left: 10%; bottom: 50%; right: 76%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 

    48% {  opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    49% { top: 50%; left: -20%; bottom: 50%; right: 122%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    

    100% { top: 50%; left: 10%; bottom: 50%; right: 76%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
.bg-ringnegen { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringnegen; 
    animation-name: bg-ringnegen; 
}

/*
bg ring 10
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringtien{ 
   0% { top: 85%; left: 85%; bottom: 15%; right: 15%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 

    48% {  opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    49% { top: 120%; left: 120%; bottom: -20%; right: -20%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    

    100% { top: 85%; left: 85%; bottom: 15%; right: 15%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringtien { 
   0% { top: 85%; left: 85%; bottom: 15%; right: 15%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 

    48% {  opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    49% { top: 120%; left: 120%; bottom: -20%; right: -20%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    

    100% { top: 85%; left: 85%; bottom: 15%; right: 15%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
.bg-ringtien { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringtien; 
    animation-name: bg-ringtien; 
}

/*
bg ring 11
*/
  
@-webkit-keyframes bg-ringelf{ 
   0% { top: 85%; left: 85%; bottom: 15%; right: 15%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 

    48% {  opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    49% { top: 120%; left: 120%; bottom: -20%; right: -20%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    

    100% { top: 85%; left: 85%; bottom: 15%; right: 15%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
@keyframes bg-ringelf { 
   0% { top: 15%; left: 15%; bottom: 85%; right: 85%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 

    48% {  opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);}
    49% { top: -20%; left: -20%; bottom: 120%; right: 120%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    50% { top: 50%; left: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 50%; opacity: 0; transform: scale(0);}
    

    100% { top: 15%; left: 15%; bottom: 85%; right: 85%; opacity: 1; transform: scale(1);} 
} 
.bg-ringelf { 
    -webkit-animation-name: bg-ringelf; 
    animation-name: bg-ringelf; 
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">

     <div class="center">
      <div class="activate-date"></div>
         <div id="knop" class="animated ring-binnen"></div>
      <div id="knop-deel2" class="animated ring-buiten"></div>
      <p id="gaop" class="text-hint active" readonly>Ga op blind meeting</p>
         <p id="beeindig"  class="text-hint hidden" readonly>Beeindig meeting</p>
         <div id="timer" class="text-timer hidden"><p> de meeting eindigt in <span id="time">02:00</span> minuten</p></div>
     </div>



         <!--   bg   -->



          <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ring"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringtwee"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringdrie"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringvier"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringzeven"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringzes"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringacht"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringnegen"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringtien"></div>

    <div class="bg-bel animated-bg bg-ringelf"></div>

     </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to stop the `setInterval()` you should use `clearInterval()` .. so you can try

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    return setInterval(function () {   // add return here
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {

            $('#gaop').removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');
            $('#beeindig').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
            $('#timer').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
            $('#knop').removeClass('begin-date').removeClass('shake');
            $('#knop-deel2').removeClass('begin-date').removeClass('shake');
            timer = duration;


        }


    }, 1000);
}
```

and

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    var twoMinutes = 60 * 2,
        display = $('#time');
    var interval = startTimer(twoMinutes, display);

    // then you can simply use in the event you want

   clearInterval(interval);
});
```

if you want to `clearInterval()` inside `setInterval()`  you can try

```
function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    var interval = setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {

            $('#gaop').removeClass('hidden').addClass('active');
            $('#beeindig').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
            $('#timer').addClass('hidden').removeClass('active');
            $('#knop').removeClass('begin-date').removeClass('shake');
            $('#knop-deel2').removeClass('begin-date').removeClass('shake');
            timer = duration;


        }else{
            clearInterval(interval);
        }


    }, 1000);
}
```

**Sample to how to use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval();`**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var interval;
  
  $('#startTimer').on('click', function(){
      interval = startTimer();
  });
  
  $('#stopTimer').on('click', function(){
      stopTimer(interval);
  });
});

var i = 0;

function startTimer(){
 return setInterval(function(){
      $('div').text(i + 1);
      i++;
  } , 1000);
}

function stopTimer(inter){
  clearInterval(inter);
}
```

```css
div{
  font-size: 20px;
  background : red;
  color: #fff;
  padding : 5px;
  text-align : center;
}

button{
  padding : 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div>0</div>
<button id="startTimer">Start Timer</button>
<button id="stopTimer">Stop Timer</button>
```

Comment: thnx i tried it but it doesn't seem to work for me in the last option it dent countdown anymore and the first it still keeps counting own for me

Comment: i have just noticed that the timer just starts when the page loads and it needs to start when the button is clicked